# How to Optimize SQL query with DISTINCT and fetch first?

Tags: sql, performance, query-optimization

I am trying to fetch first 5 distinct rows using the query **`SELECT DISTINCT col_A from table_name fetch first 5 rows only;`**

But the table has millions of rows so using distinct is expensive as it scans the whole table for only 5 rows taking a lot of time, around 200 seconds for me.

Is there a workaround or subquery for this?

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: And then it's a surprise *which* 5 rows are returned, as there is no `ORDER BY`

Comment: As @HoneyBadger already implies: there is no 'first' when no `order by` is given. If you really don't care about the order, then why not simply fetch 100 rows and do a distinct on that? If it turns out there are less than 5 unique records present then ask for 500 or 1000 or ... I don't know your situation but in a lot of situations such an approach might work. Off course, if you need 'first' then this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is you don't know if a row is unique unless you check all the other rows. I believe your only solution would be to index the rows such that non-distinct rows are indexed together. That might buy you some efficiency when searching, however it will cost you when inserting data.

Comment: Specifically, create the index with `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX col_A (col_A);` then add `ORDER BY col_A` to the end of your query. It should become almost instantaneous.

Comment: Indexing makes sense but I dont have write access, sorry I forgot to mention.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there is any way to improve your search using a different query approach, there is no way to discern logically which data is distinct without querying the entire table.